Sql , find transaction table within 10 days
We have a transaction table where we have following columns:
tx id, tx date, tx user, entity id, tx amount, tx location 

We want to get all the transactions of a user and its transaction details who has done the 2nd transactions within last 10 days. 
Here are the queries are used
    CREATE TABLE Transaction_details(
        tx_id int,
        tx_date date,
        tx_user varchar(50),
        entity_id INT,
        tx_amount DECIMAL(10,2),
        tx_location VARCHAR(255),
    );
    
    INSERT INTO Transaction_details(tx_id,tx_date,tx_user,entity_id,tx_amount,tx_location)
            VALUES(1,'2024-04-20','Alice',101,50.00,'Seattle');
    INSERT INTO Transaction_details(tx_id,tx_date,tx_user,entity_id,tx_amount,tx_location)
            VALUES(2,'2024-04-25','Bob',102,75.50,'New York');
    INSERT INTO Transaction_details(tx_id,tx_date,tx_user,entity_id,tx_amount,tx_location)
            VALUES(3,   '2024-04-28','Carol',103,30.20,'Los Angeles');
    
    Select * from Transaction_details;
    
    INSERT INTO Transaction_details(tx_id,tx_date,tx_user,entity_id,tx_amount,tx_location)
            VALUES(4,'2024-04-30','Alice',104,500.00,'Seattle');
    INSERT INTO Transaction_details(tx_id,tx_date,tx_user,entity_id,tx_amount,tx_location)
            VALUES(5,'2024-05-08','Bob',105,70.00,'Chicago');  
    INSERT INTO Transaction_details(tx_id,tx_date,tx_user,entity_id,tx_amount,tx_location)
            VALUES(6,'2024-05-05','Alice',106,100.00,'Newyork');
    
    SELECT *
    FROM Transaction_details
    WHERE tx_user IN (
        SELECT tx_user
        FROM (
            SELECT tx_user, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tx_user ORDER BY tx_date) AS t
            FROM Transaction_details
        ) AS numbered
        WHERE t = 2
    )
    AND tx_date >= 
      (SELECT DATEDIFF(day,GETDATE(),'2022-04-04') from Transaction_details);

my ms sql server showing the error message in tx_date condition and year getdate function

The question mentions ms sql server but you have tagged mysql and the error message you state don't match either https://dbfiddle.uk/sAg9M1vx https://dbfiddle.uk/Q6q7FodV Please publish error message in full.

You appear to have mixed difficult date conditions and that's not allowed. As your query currently stands, it tries to compare a date with a number and that's of course not possible. You need to either go x days back or to compare one date with another. See https://dbfiddle.uk/PFeXJCO0

Please tag your question properly!  I am sure MySQL does not have GETDATE().

Not sure why you have so many subqueries, or why you are using DATEDIFF instead of DATEADD.
Looks like you just need:
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
      td.*,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY td.tx_user ORDER BY td.tx_date) AS t
    FROM Transaction_details td
) AS numbered
WHERE t = 2
  AND tx_date >= DATEADD(day, -10, GETDATE());

You may possible have wanted "the second or any later transaction in the last 10 days" in which case a simpler solution is available
SELECT
  td.tx_user
FROM Transaction_details td
GROUP BY
  td.tx_user
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
  AND MAX(td.tx_date) >= DATEADD(day, -10, GETDATE());

